# Images: copyright and links

Tags: discussion

Since we're just starting here, we need to set the tone when it comes to using external images. I've seen [two](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/359/51) [answers](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/445/51) where an external image was embedded without any link to the source. (I've edited the answers to include a link to the source, but the edits need to be approved.)

It may not be legal at all to embed such images (if they are not in the public domain) or even [CC-BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) images without proper attribution. So, please (1) use images that are legal to use (2) at least link to the source.

(See also [this related discussion on meta.spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77/embedding-images-and-copyright-issues).)

Answer (score 11):

A very good point, something we definitely should keep in mind. Users should be encouraged to try to find CC-licensed (creative commons), other permissively licensed, or public domain images (and comply with attribution requirements) whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed it.   At the bottom of the image upload box is a [policy link](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

[image: upload your image]

Comment: That's a great find Paparazzi! This policy is clear, but in very small writing. Since this is an old discussion, I don't know whether or not people have been more careful, but this states clearly that we should. Thanks!